# Header Menu CSS Issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've been having two css issues on techprosecurity.com that I've been having a hard time figuring out how to repair. The NAV menu in the header has a small space when you hover over any link that is not currently selected as an active one. I have searched for any attribute that may remove that spacing without damaging the look of the menu but unfortunately have been unsuccessful.

example: 
[image]

My second issue is that on mobile the submenu links on the navbar end up hiding behind the main slider image and requires users to scroll the menu in order to see and click on any submenu links. I have tried changing the Z-Index on many of the styles but can't get it to sit over the image. However, It is working on ipads and possibly other tablets where the links actually sits above the image.

example on mobile: ''/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-15%20at%202.01.06%20PM.png

example on tablet: ''/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-15%20at%202.01.22%20PM.png

If anyone can help that would be awesome!

Comment: Any Code ? no-pictures..

Comment: @AwRak - he has pics just no code.

Comment: @Th Dro - Can you post the code please? Looking at the pics it seems like the misalignment could be caused by the "up" arrow but it's tough to help you fix it without any code

Comment: I see the problem. What is your goal when it comes to the small blue arrow pointing up? Should that arrow only show on active nav buttons?

Comment: I didn't post the code because there's a lot of things going on for that site. If you go to the techprosecurity.com website and see the menu you will be able to inspect element in order to see the issues with the styling. If I definitely have to post the code, I can copy it and edit my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.menu ul>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent; <-- REMOVE THIS
}
```

Remove the border-bottom

Second Problem:
 its a bootstrap issue:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: auto; <-- CHANGE TO INHERIT
}
```

Comment: he need's the "transparent" part to show his little blue arrow though.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for the space under the links along with what @AdamBuchananSmith mentioned below your comment. Now I only need to understand why the z-index is having issues. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes to catch the conflict!

Comment: I think I was able to find out why it's still adding a border under the selected menu item when you Hover over it. It looks like in the CSS there's a border being added to the LI, as well as the a:hover so it's adding it twice to the current selected item and then again on hover state.

Answer (score 0):

Add a little extra padding at the bottom of the links that are not selected,  I think `padding-bottom: 34px;` will do it for you, currently the space is coming from the little blue arrow that only shows on the selected link, so to compensate a little extra padding to the bottom of the un selected links.

Comment: I notice even when I add this  I still get a bit of a jumping effect when the mouse leaves the link. I'm checking the :active and :hover states now to see what I can find.

Comment: if its jumping down, remove 1px of padding and if its jumping up add 1px. I put an aprox. size as a starting point for you.

Comment: The size worked out fine, but it's when you release the hover is when you see the jump. If you are looking at the link  and hover over it, it works fine, but when you move the mouse away is when you see the jumping im referring to.

Comment: @The Dro you want to keep the transparency, do not remove it like the above answer stated, rather ad 34px of padding like this `.menu-link .main-menu-link {padding-bottom: 34px;}`

Comment: The no transparency is screwing everything up.